# SuperUser has wrong answer in one of its tests

Tags: support, bug, review, review-audits

I was just volunteering some time reviewing First Posts, and SuperUser presented an answer regarding not Broadcasting SSID's.  The answer was technically correct, but ***very*** misleading.  I took my time to write a thoughtful and well-researched comment in order to provide better context.

When I submitted the comment, the SuperUser system said I failed the test because the answer was correct and the only appropriate action was to upvote it or do nothing.

In fact, *the thing that failed was the SuperUser system!*

After it said that I "failed", it showed the comments to the answer (which were hidden during the test), which finally revealed the misleading nature of the answer, and asked why that answer had so many upvotes.

My comment, and the time I spent composing it, was lost.

It appears the test was created by someone or something without sufficient knowledge or experience to be writing tests.  :-)

Comment: Another day, another bad review audit.

Comment: Very true, and unfortunately it discourages community participation.

Comment: Tip: Reviewing can include right clicking on one of the links (like a title) and opening in a new tab the total of the Q&A, so you can see what's up with the whole Q&A, before making descisions on what you see in the review.  It certannly wont keep a person from getting caught/trapped/screwed in the review system, but often there are more clues when viewing the whole thing.

Comment: If in doubt view the question review audits are extremely easy to recognize, is it bad when 90% of them, are question you have viewed personally and already acted on?

Comment: I wish the SE folks would put a "dispute" button (allowing the reviewer to provide an explanation).  when a user has "failed" and audit question.  This could be implemented like the Moderator message flagging  operation.  This would hopefully allow some interactive feedback so the the SE people can improve the programming in this area.

Comment: @mdpc I guess they like telling us we "failed", but don't want to hear that, in fact, they failed.